# in redux-form, how to restrict the values of the input to a range?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I want the user to be able to type numbers up to 2000, and anything beyond 2000 would be simply fed back into the input as '2000'.

```
<input type="number"   className="no-spin"
                       min="0" max="2000"
                       value={???}
                       {...eval(`${meal}_salt_amt_1`)} />
```

BTW, the 'max' attribute only stops the user from using the up-arrow to increment above 2000.

And redux-form's 'validate' function doesn't restrict what can be typed.

Here is how I'm restricting the value (in state) to 2000...

```
export function updateStats(values) {
    for (var value in values){
        if (value.search('salt_amt') >= 0) {
            if ( values[value] > 2000) values[value] = 2000;
        }
    }
    return {
        type: UPDATE_STATS,
        stats: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(values))
    };
}
```

... so far so good, because in my DevTools redux plugin, I can see the state of these values topping out at 2000.

But how do I force that state back into my redux-form input fields?

Mapping the state to props and using the prop isn't working. Doing so lets me type any number over 2000...

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        ...
        breakfast_salt_amt_1: state.stats.breakfast_salt_amt_1,
        ...
    }
}

<input type="number"   className="no-spin"
                       min="0" max="2000"
                       value={breakfast_salt_amt_1}
                       {...breakfast_salt_amt_1} />
```

And just using the state isn't working either...

```
<input type="number"   className="no-spin"
                       min="0" max="2000"
                       value={state.stats.breakfast_salt_amt_1}
                       {...breakfast_salt_amt_1} />

// =>  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stats' of null
```

What have I forgotten?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what [Normalizing](http://redux-form.com/6.4.1/examples/normalizing/) is for. Something like this (untested):

```
const under2k = value => {
  if(value < 0) {
    return 0
  } else if(value > 2000) {
    return 2000
  } else {
    return value
  }
}

<Field
  name="breakfastSaltAmt"
  component="input"
  type="number"
  normalize={under2k}/>
```

Comment: Thanks sir. Wouldn't have known to search for the term "normalize".

Comment: I wouldn't know what else to call it. :-D Glad I could help.

Comment: Is there a way to pass the compared value (i.e 2000) as an argument instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
export const maxLenght = max => value => {

    let v;
    let result = value.length > max;

    if(result === false) {
        v = value;
    }
    return v;
};

<Field
      name="name"
      type="text"
      component={renderField}
      label="Nome Completo *"
      placeholder="Nome Completo"
      normalize={maxLenght(10)}
    />
```

Comment: Format your answer add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you:

```
<input type="number"   className="no-spin"
                       min="0" max="2000"
                       value={this.props.breakfast_salt_amt_1}
                       {...breakfast_salt_amt_1} />
```

Comment: My bad,Instead of writing this.props i wrote this.state

Comment: unfortunately the state (mapped to props) isn't changing the input - as seen in this picture https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/lkj2dewi3ofvkgc/5_lwk-p6.jpg. When I put this.props.breakfast_salt_amt_1 in other EMPTY input boxes, it populates those, but it doesn't overwrite the existing 5000 and replace it with 2000.

Comment: can you please explain me what is this {...breakfast_salt_amt_1}

Comment: this.props.breakfast_salt_amt_1 is working on other input boxes?

Comment: {...breakfast_salt_amt_1} comes from const {
            breakfast_salt_1,breakfast_salt_amt_1,breakfast_salt_2,breakfast_salt_amt_2} = this.props.fields;

Comment: {...breakfast_salt_amt_1} is the way redux-form gives all of its input boxes the required attributes. The triple dot is destructuring the breakfast_salt_amt_1 object, which is created by redux-form once you set it up in the configObject. It is redux-form that is making the input box hard to change using the usual methods, I think...

Comment: and this.props.breakfast_salt_amt_1 IS working on other EMPTY input boxes. It's just not overwriting any values have already been typed in.

Comment: in your reducer you are not returning ...state

Comment: what version of redux-form you are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131529/discussion-between-dwilbank-and-codesingh).